# I have a route to the network but from the traceroute output it doesn't leave the server

Tags: networking, hp-ux, route, traceroute

I have an HP-UX box and I'm trying to determine why a host can't be reached. I'm trying to reach the host 10.32.13.146

```
root@hp-ux:/root # traceroute -I 10.32.13.146

traceroute to 10.32.13.146 (10.32.13.146), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
```

I already have a route to the network as seen below - 10.32.13.128/255.255.255.128    10.32.32.1.

```
root@hp-ux:/root # netstat -rnv Routing tables Dest/Netmask           
Gateway            Flags Refs Interface  Pmtu
127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255       127.0.0.1          UH    0    lo0       32808
10.32.32.25/255.255.255.255     10.32.32.25        UH    0    lan901    32808
142.40.216.27/255.255.255.255   142.40.216.27      UH    0    lan900    32808
142.40.216.0/255.255.255.128    142.40.216.27      U     2    lan900     1500
10.32.32.0/255.255.255.128      10.32.32.25        U     2    lan901     1500
10.32.33.0/255.255.255.128      10.32.32.1         UG    0    lan901     1500
10.32.37.0/255.255.255.128      10.32.32.1         UG    0    lan901     1500
10.32.46.128/255.255.255.128    10.32.32.1         UG    0    lan901     1500
10.106.132.128/255.255.255.128  10.32.32.1         UG    0    lan901     1500
10.32.13.128/255.255.255.128    10.32.32.1         UG    0    lan901     1500
10.106.129.0/255.255.255.0      10.32.32.1         UG    0    lan901     1500
127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0             127.0.0.1          U     0    lo0       32808
default/0.0.0.0                 142.40.216.1       UG    0   lan900     1500
```

Does anybody can explain what's wrong with this server and how to fix this situation?

Edit:
No problems reaching 10.32.32.25

```
root@hp-ux:/root# ping 10.32.32.25 -n 1
PING 10.32.32.25: 64 byte packets
64 bytes from 10.32.32.25: icmp_seq=0. time=0. ms

----10.32.32.25 PING Statistics----
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip (ms)  min/avg/max = 0/0/0
```

Here is the /etc/rc.config.d/netconf

```
root@hp-ux:/root# grep -v ^# /etc/rc.config.d/netconf

HOSTNAME="hp-ux"
OPERATING_SYSTEM=HP-UX
LOOPBACK_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1




ROUTE_DESTINATION[0]="default"
ROUTE_MASK[0]=""
ROUTE_GATEWAY[0]="142.40.216.1"
ROUTE_COUNT[0]="1"
ROUTE_ARGS[0]=""
ROUTE_SOURCE[0]=""


GATED=0
GATED_ARGS=""


RDPD=0


RARPD=0


DEFAULT_INTERFACE_MODULES=""
INTERFACE_NAME[1]="lan900"
IP_ADDRESS[1]="142.40.216.27"
SUBNET_MASK[1]="255.255.255.128"
BROADCAST_ADDRESS[1]="142.40.216.127"
INTERFACE_STATE[1]="up"
DHCP_ENABLE[1]="0"
INTERFACE_MODULES[1]=""
INTERFACE_NAME[2]="lan901"
IP_ADDRESS[2]="10.32.32.25"
SUBNET_MASK[2]="255.255.255.128"
BROADCAST_ADDRESS[2]="10.32.32.127"
INTERFACE_STATE[2]="up"
DHCP_ENABLE[2]="0"
INTERFACE_MODULES[2]=""
ROUTE_DESTINATION[1]="net 10.32.33.0"
ROUTE_GATEWAY[1]=10.32.32.1
ROUTE_COUNT[1]=1
ROUTE_MASK[1]=255.255.255.128
ROUTE_ARGS[1]=
ROUTE_DESTINATION[3]="net 10.32.46.128"
ROUTE_GATEWAY[3]=10.32.32.1
ROUTE_COUNT[3]=1
ROUTE_MASK[3]=255.255.255.128
ROUTE_ARGS[3]=
ROUTE_DESTINATION[2]="net 10.32.37.0"
ROUTE_GATEWAY[2]=10.32.32.1
ROUTE_COUNT[2]=1
ROUTE_MASK[2]=255.255.255.128
ROUTE_ARGS[2]=
ROUTE_DESTINATION[4]="net 10.106.129.0"
ROUTE_GATEWAY[4]=10.32.32.1
ROUTE_COUNT[4]=1
ROUTE_MASK[4]=255.255.255.0
ROUTE_ARGS[4]=
ROUTE_DESTINATION[5]="net 10.106.132.128"
ROUTE_GATEWAY[5]=10.32.32.1
ROUTE_COUNT[5]=1
ROUTE_MASK[5]=255.255.255.128
ROUTE_ARGS[5]=
ROUTE_DESTINATION[6]="net 10.32.13.128"
ROUTE_GATEWAY[6]=10.32.32.1
ROUTE_COUNT[6]=1
ROUTE_MASK[6]=255.255.255.128
ROUTE_ARGS[6]=
```

Comment: You can't have a gateway (10.32.32.1) that's outside of the subnet. Are you sure that netmask is correct?

Comment: and you can reach 10.32.32.25?

Comment: to say the least, your routing table looks quite unusual. are you sure you are able to get to anywhere 10.32.x.x network ? Please post the contents of your /etc/rc.config.d/netconf file and if there is any other home made scripts that you are using to create additional interfaces and routes, please post them too.

Comment: The routes look OK to me.  Your gateway is on the same subnet, and you have a route through it to your destination.  You need to make sure that 10.32.32.1 is actually acting as a gateway, and that it will respond to ICMP ECHO packets.  Some admins turn off ping responses.

Comment: @KyleJones No, 10.32.32.1 is not in the 10.32.13.128/25 subnet.

Comment: @setatakahashi Where did you get your network settings from?  10.32.32.1 is an invalid gateway for most of those subnets.  Ask your network admin for the correct settings.

Comment: @depquid Yes, but 10.32.32.1 is being used as a gateway and it may be able to talk to 10.32.13.128/25 on another interface.  There's no way to know whether it can from this table, but assuming that it can there's nothing wrong with the route.

Comment: 10.32.32.1 is reachable on the network and is routing the packages. We inspected and the problem was that the other host was not responding the requests. Nothing to do with the configuration on this HP-UX server.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone else who runs across this post:

The computer in this situation has 2 network interfaces. One (lan901) is assigned static IP 10.32.32.1 and therefore absolutely is reachable by the computer... duh!

Cap